# How to sync tasks using FreeRTOS library?

Tags: freertos

I have 5 tasks(function) in 5 different which are running simultaneously. I want to implement like any function start running then other function should not run until the function completes its process.
I want to implement using FreeRTOS.
**Example.**

- foo1.c
  ->Task1
- foo2.c
  ->Task2
- foo3.c
  ->Task3
- foo4.c
  ->Task4
- foo5.c
  ->Task5

Comment: Why is this tagged with C and C++? Why with AWS? What exactly do you mean with "task"? There is a lot of context missing from your question. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a [mutex](https://www.freertos.org/Real-time-embedded-RTOS-mutexes.html). Each task acquires the mutex when they start running, and release it when they are done. When any of the tasks is running, others are blocked on the mutex.

Comment: Can we use a counting semaphore? How Can tell me some basic idea?

Comment: It depends on the nature of your *shared resource* which prevents simultaneous execution of multiple tasks. You didn't tell the details of your problem. Please add additional information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a mutex (mutually exclusive) semaphore.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/feilipu/Arduino_FreeRTOS_Library/blob/master/examples/GoldilocksAnalogueTestSuite/GoldilocksAnalogueTestSuite.ino#L58) protecting the Serial Port of an ATmega Arduino Clone. This ensures that messages presented to the serial port by multiple tasks are not interleaved (corrupted).

[You can see that the semaphore is taken](https://github.com/feilipu/Arduino_FreeRTOS_Library/blob/master/examples/GoldilocksAnalogueTestSuite/GoldilocksAnalogueTestSuite.ino#L217) before attempting to write to the serial port, and then given (freed) when the task has completed its activities.